# Protect Files from unauthorized access

Tags: php, html, security, authorization

I have this very big problem I've been trying to solve for last few days with no success. I have some files which are class schedules, these are imported to the server from an external source (html format). I need to block direct access to those files. They are displayed by PHP script. So, these are assumptions:
-files displayed via php script
-files cannot be modified in any way (html files)
-there must be no direct access to those files
-server is apache

any ideas? I tried with htaccess, but I may be not competent enough, because it was blocking access to files for php script too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.htaccess`

**Sample RewriteRule**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder/$ http://path_to_different_page.php
```

Comment: thanks everyone and especially You, it is the simpliest and the most efficient way I think :)

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

I think another way is :

1. create a key-value table, rename the file, the old name is key and the value is the new one(may be md5('xx') or other long/irregular/unique string) .
2. lookup the 'key-value' table when access the files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking for one or more files protection using .htaccess then you could do something like below ...

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/to/passwordfile/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files admin.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
<Files protected.htm>
require valid-user
</Files>
<Files protected2.htm>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

You'll need to create one .htpasswd file too and update the `AuthUserFile` path to location of this file .... There is a tool availabe at http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/ to create these `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files.

Answer (score 0):

> files displayed via php script

Store the passwords somewhere ([securely](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)). HTML form to submit credentials. `$_POST` to read them. PDO to read them. [include](http://php.net/include) to include the files if the user is authorised.

> -files cannot be modified in any way (html files)

All the logic goes in PHP. All the credentials are stored externally.

> -there must be no direct access to those files

Keep the files outside the DocumentRoot.